# TXR: writing recursive pattern matching directives

Tags: recursion, grammar, text-processing, txr

I'm having trouble understanding how to write recursive pattern matching functions in TXR. Below I try to define a recursive directive for recognizing file paths. I know in this case I can represent this grammar with a regular expression `([a-z]+\/)+[a-z]+`, but I have a more complex rule set in mind for my real code that would benefit from it. What is causing this directive to fail when there is a forward slash?

```
@(define location)@\
@  (cases)@\
@/[a-z]+/@\
@  (or)@\
@/[a-z]+//@(location)@\
@  (end)@\
@(end)
@(repeat)
@(cases)
@{location (location)}
@  (output)
@location is a valid location.
@  (end)
@(or)
@location
@  (output)
@location is not a valid location.
@  (end)
@(end)
@(end)
```

Example valid inputs:

```
this/is/valid
this/is/also/valid
this
a/b/c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Of course, you're almost certainly aware that `location` is matching a regular language which we can just munge with a regex: `/[a-z]+(\/[a-z]+)*/`. I'm assuming this is just a "recursion hello world" warm-up for something more complicated.)

The thing about `cases` is that it uses top to bottom, short-circuited evaluation. The second case cannot match since the first case matches its prefix. It's not like a regex branch operator where the order of the subexpressions doesn't matter.

If I simply swap the two cases, the sample works for me.

What also works (in this particular case) is changing `cases` to `some`. The `some` directive doesn't stop at the first match.

Using `some` is not a cure-all for this sort of `cases` ordering problem because sometimes you  need to short circuit around a case to terminate recursion (for instance, avoid left-recursing when some condition is hit) or to avoid degenerate performance (exponential time). I'm reminded of a university professor's joke: *"you've heard of divide and conquer; this is multiply and surrender"*.

`some` also has the property that the later clauses "see" bindings from earlier successfully matching clauses. That might interfere with it being a solution for a `cases`-ordering problem. That is to say, the later clause might fail to match due to a variable clash. The `:resolve` feature of `some` might be helpful in that situation or might not.

Comment: I will remember "multiply and surrender" :)

Comment: Here is the "multiply and surrender" guy himself, so you can attribute it to somewhere: https://www.math.ubc.ca/~anstee/